# Logging not captured on behave steps

Tags: python, logging, bdd, python-behave

Ok so in my environment.py file I am able to log stuff by:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename="example.log")

def before_feature(context, feature):
    logging.info("test logging")
```

but when I am inside the steps file I cannot perform logging:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

@given("we have a step")
def step_impl(context):
    logger.debug("Test logging 2")
```

The logging message inside the step does not show up. I am using the python behave module. Any ideas?

I have tried enabling and disabling logcapture when I run behave but it makes no difference.

Comment: Do you mean it is not appearing in the console output or in the example.log file?

Comment: Do a full-text search through `*.py` to check who *else* is calling `logging.basicConfig` in your project. I've seen it called in places like `__init__.py` silently affecting anyone who imports a module from the package where such a file is present.

Answer (score 6):

By default, behave tends to capture logs during feature execution, and only display them in cases of failure.

To disable this, you can set
`log_capture=false`
in behave.ini

Or, you can use the `--no-logcapture` command line option

Further Reading : [Behave API Reference](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html#cmdoption-no-logcapture), [Behave LogCapture](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#logging-capture)

Comment: Thank you; saved my day! Maybe it's just me but I don't find the official documentation very helpful.

Comment: Still `behave` captures logging even with `--no-logcapture`, when using the default formatter. Only when I set `--format=plain --no-logcapture`, I can see the logs. This is terribly annoying.

Answer (score 5):

what worked for me:

```
behave --no-capture --no-capture-stderr --no-logcapture
```

and add in the environment.py the follwing snipest:

```
    def after_step(context, step):
        print("")
```

Why: I disovered that behave does not log the last print statement of a step. So I just added a empty print after each step with the previous snipest.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Importing logging from environment.py in steps.py solved problem for me.

`from features.environment import logging`

I am not sure but I guess the problem is that every time you import logging it rewrites your previous configs because `disable_existing_loggers` is True by default. ([Here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) is the documentation paragraph explaining this)